# C# How to Cast Dictionary<string, object> to a type?

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting

I've run into this interesting issue where I get an `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'` while trying to cast my `object` inside my `Dictionary<string, object>` to and `(int)`. Inside this Dictionary I store state for the current Game someone is playing and want to `re-save / re-load` the data if the game requires a save or has been closed. This method is only for reading the save not saving it.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Code:

```
public async Task ReadGameFileInAsync(string gameVersion)
{
    var gameSave = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if (gameVersion == "bronze")
        gameSave = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(await ReadFileInAsync(BronzeGameSaveFilePath));
    else if (gameVersion == "silver")
        gameSave = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(await ReadFileInAsync(SilverGameSaveFilePath));

    _GameStats.CurrentGame = (int)gameSave["CurrentGame"]; //Error throws here.
    _GameStats.CurrentWord = (int)gameSave["CurrentWord"];
    _GameStats.Score = (int)gameSave["Score"];
    _GameStats.BestScore = (int)gameSave["BestScore"];
    _GameStats.Difficulty = (int)gameSave["Difficulty"];
    _GameStats.IsNewGame = (bool)gameSave["IsNewGame"];
    _GameStats.IsContinue = (bool)gameSave["IsContinue"];
    _GameStats.IsUnlocked = (bool)gameSave["IsUnlocked"];
    _GameStats.GameVersion = (string)gameSave["GameVersion"];
    _GameStats.Cards = (ObservableCollection<LevelCardGroup>)gameSave["Cards"];
}
```

GameStats:

```
public class GameStats : IGameStats
{
    public int CurrentGame { get; set; } = 1;
    public int CurrentWord { get; set; } = 1;
    public int Score { get; set; } = 0;
    public int BestScore { get; set; } = 0;
    public bool IsNewGame { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsContinue { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsUnlocked { get; set; } = false;
    public bool ContinueButtonPressed { get; set; } = false;
    public string GameVersion { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Difficulty { get; set; } = 3;
    public ObservableCollection<LevelCardGroup> Cards { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<LevelCardGroup>();

    public void ResetGameStats(string gameVersion = "")
    {
        CurrentGame = 1;
        CurrentWord = 1;
        Score = 0;
        BestScore = 0;
        IsNewGame = true;
        IsContinue = false;
        GameVersion = gameVersion;
        Difficulty = 3;
        Cards.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: A.) what type have you stored as "CurrentGame" and B.) Why is it a Dictionary? For example you could have just serialized _GameStats(or a class with a surface that looks pretty much like _GameStats) and get a somewhat more typesafe serialization.

Comment: @Ralf I've added my GameStats. I could create a GameStatsController where I can add my ResetGameStats Method and make the GameStats serializable.

Comment: Whatever you've stored in your dictionary at `gameSave["CurrentGame"]` is apparently not an `int`.

Comment: Yeah I'm confused about that because when I debug it shows `1`...

Comment: What prevents you from serializing and deserializing `GameStats` directly?

Comment: I get an `Error Message` says `GameStats is a type, which is not valid in the given context`... What ever that means.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist `1` is a valid value for multiple number types. And you need to cast exactly to correct one (implicit/explicit conversions would be used during cast). What does `gameSave["CurrentGame"].GetType()` results in?

Comment: Try changing `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>` to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameStats>` and change the declaration to `var gameSave = new GameStats();`

Comment: _"debug it shows 1"_ - `1` or `"1"` ?

Comment: @GuruStron I do not want a new instance of my GameStats and I already register it as a`DependecyService` I do not need any new instances.

Comment: @Fildor `1` not `"1"`

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist then copy data from deserialized `GameStats` to the existing one. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>` will create a new instance of dictionary, what is the major difference here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deserialize to the class instance and copy data from it:

```cs
public async Task ReadGameFileInAsync(string gameVersion)
{
    var gameSave = gameVersion switch
    {
        "bronze" => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameStats>(await ReadFileInAsync(BronzeGameSaveFilePath)),
        "silver" => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameStats>(await ReadFileInAsync(SilverGameSaveFilePath)),
        _ => null
    };

    if (gameSave is not null)
    {
        _GameStats.CurrentGame = gameSave.CurrentGame; // or maybe better create a copy from method
        //  ...
    }
    else
    {
        // todo: throw? clear game stats?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after further testing my solution didn't work. Tried this one and it works as expected. Althought had to tweak it a little because I'm still on C# 7.3 on this project and unfortunately cannot use new features that I love.... annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the Newtonsoft JSON converter.

When you deserialize your JSON, the `gameSave["CurrentGame"]` might be the type of `Int64` which can not be directly converted to `int` since it can store larger values.

You can try to convert it with `Convert.ToInt32(gameSave["CurrentGame"])`, and you would be probably fine, since I guess your game IDs won't overflow the `int`.

The next time you run into any problem like this you can check the type of your variable with `gameSave["CurrentGame"].GetType().Name` and see where it goes wrong.

But as Robert Harvey mentioned, you would be probably better off directly deserializing it into the class you are using.

Answer (score -1):

How about doing this

```
    _GameStats.CurrentGame = (gameSave["CurrentGame"] is int) ? (int)gameSave["CurrentGame"] : _GameStats.CurrentGame;
    _GameStats.CurrentWord = (gameSave["CurrentWord"] is int) ? (int)gameSave["CurrentWord"] : _GameStats.CurrentWord;
    _GameStats.Score = (gameSave["Score"] is int) ? (int)gameSave["Score"] : _GameStats.Score;
    _GameStats.BestScore = (gameSave["BestScore"] is int) ? (int)gameSave["BestScore"] : _GameStats.BestScore;
    _GameStats.Difficulty = (gameSave["Difficulty"] is int) ? (int)gameSave["Difficulty"] : _GameStats.Difficulty;
    _GameStats.IsNewGame = (gameSave["IsNewGame"] is bool) ? (bool)gameSave["IsNewGame"] : _GameStats.IsNewGame;
    _GameStats.IsContinue = (gameSave["IsContinue"] is bool) ? (bool)gameSave["IsContinue"] : _GameStats.IsContinue;
    _GameStats.IsUnlocked = (gameSave["IsUnlocked"] is bool) ? (bool)gameSave["IsUnlocked"] : _GameStats.IsUnlocked;
    _GameStats.GameVersion = (gameSave["GameVersion"] is string) ? (string)gameSave["GameVersion"] : _GameStats.GameVersion;
    _GameStats.Cards = (gameSave["Cards"] is ObservableCollection<LevelCardGroup>) ? (ObservableCollection<LevelCardGroup>)gameSave["Cards"] : _GameStats.Cards;
```